# Saving the n grams python generator output as cvs file

Tags: python, csv, nltk

I am finding the n grams from a text data in python.

I have used the NLTK package to get that. Here is the code

```
from nltk.util import ngrams
bigrams=ngrams(cleaned_docs,2)
trigrams=ngrams(cleaned_docs,3)
quadgrams=ngrams(cleaned_docs,4)
pentagrams=ngrams(cleaned_docs,5)
```

Here cleaned_docs is a list of tokenized words from a text. Each returned type is a generator here with values as tuples of n grams. For bi gram this is how it looks:

```
for x in bigrams:
    print x

("mom's", 'hi')
('this', 'in')
('in', 'house')
```

I want to get a frequency distribution of each n grams as defined above and save them in a cvs file in descending order of frequency. The csv will have two columns One is the n gram name and the other corresponding count in the text.

Also I would want to plot the frequency of the n grams as save that figure as .jpeg file too. Here is the code I used to plot unigrams or word frequency. But not sure how this nltk fd object is used to save it as jpeg.

```
fd = nltk.FreqDist(cleaned_docs)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,15))
plt.ylabel("frequency",fontsize=25)
plt.xlabel("Words",fontsize=25)
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=15) 
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=15)
plt.title("Word Frequency Distribution",fontsize=25)
fd.plot(80,cumulative=False)
```

Please note I am looking for a faster solution because my text is huge. I have 550K observations and each observation has more than 500 character text data on an average. So no. of bigrams and n grams would be huge too.

Answer (score 0):

The `nltk.FreqDist` class is a sub-class of python's [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), so there is nothing special about it. It will count occurrences of each elemet in the iterable you are passing to it.

```
n2_freq = ntlk.FreqDist(bigrams)
```

To get the elements in descending frequency order you can use the [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method.

```
for bigram, freq in n2_freq.most_common():
    # Print them...
```

To save the figure you'd use the `fig` object returned by `plt.figure`, it should have a [`savefig`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.savefig) method.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,15))
[...]
n2_freq.plot()

fig.savefig('bigram_freq_dist.jpg')
```

As you can see on the [source of `plot` function](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/probability.py#L215) it doesn't return anything.